# RStudio Tabularx Table Not Centering

Tags: latex, tabular

Automated LaTeX code generated in RStudio using *jtools* and *huxtable*. Unfortunately the table is not exactly centered on page. Struggling to identify where the fault may lie. Obviously `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` is not working. I also attempted to use `\makebox[\linewidth]` command but to no avail.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}  
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,frame,center]{crop}
\begin{document}

  \providecommand{\huxb}[2]{\arrayrulecolor[RGB]{#1}\global\arrayrulewidth=#2pt}
  \providecommand{\huxvb}[2]{\color[RGB]{#1}\vrule width #2pt}
  \providecommand{\huxtpad}[1]{\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+#1}}
  \providecommand{\huxbpad}[1]{\rule[-#1]{0pt}{#1}}

\begin{center}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{p{0.1\textwidth} p{0.1\textwidth} p{0.1\textwidth} p{0.1\textwidth} p{0.1\textwidth}}

\hhline{>{\huxb{0, 0, 0}{0.8}}->{\huxb{0, 0, 0}{0.8}}->{\huxb{0, 0, 0}{0.8}}->{\huxb{0, 0, 0}{0.8}}->{\huxb{0, 0, 0}{0.8}}-}
\arrayrulecolor{black}

\multicolumn{1}{!{\huxvb{0, 0, 0}{0}}c!{\huxvb{0, 0, 0}{0}}}{\huxtpad{4pt}\centering \huxbpad{4pt}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c!{\huxvb{0, 0, 0}{0}}}{\huxtpad{4pt}\centering Model 1\huxbpad{4pt}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c!{\huxvb{0, 0, 0}{0}}}{\huxtpad{4pt}\centering Model 2\huxbpad{4pt}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c!{\huxvb{0, 0, 0}{0}}}{\huxtpad{4pt}\centering Model 3\huxbpad{4pt}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c!{\huxvb{0, 0, 0}{0}}}{\huxtpad{4pt}\centering Model 4\huxbpad{4pt}} \tabularnewline[-0.5pt]

\hhline{>{\huxb{255, 255, 255}{0.4}}->{\huxb{0, 0, 0}{0.4}}->{\huxb{0, 0, 0}{0.4}}->{\huxb{0, 0, 0}{0.4}}->{\huxb{0, 0, 0}{0.4}}-}
\arrayrulecolor{black}

\multicolumn{1}{!{\huxvb{0, 0, 0}{0}}l!{\huxvb{0, 0, 0}{0}}}{\huxtpad{4pt}\raggedright VariablesInterventionIncumbent\huxbpad{4pt}} &
\multicolumn{1}{r!{\huxvb{0, 0, 0}{0}}}{\huxtpad{4pt}\raggedleft ~~~~~~~~~\huxbpad{4pt}} &
\multicolumn{1}{r!{\huxvb{0, 0, 0}{0}}}{\huxtpad{4pt}\raggedleft ~~~~~~~~~\huxbpad{4pt}} &
\multicolumn{1}{r!{\huxvb{0, 0, 0}{0}}}{\huxtpad{4pt}\raggedleft -0.0115~~~~\huxbpad{4pt}} &
\multicolumn{1}{r!{\huxvb{0, 0, 0}{0}}}{\huxtpad{4pt}\raggedleft 0.1432~~~~\huxbpad{4pt}} \tabularnewline[-0.5pt]

\hhline{>{\huxb{255, 255, 255}{0.4}}->{\huxb{0, 0, 0}{0.4}}->{\huxb{0, 0, 0}{0.4}}->{\huxb{0, 0, 0}{0.4}}->{\huxb{0, 0, 0}{0.4}}-}
\arrayrulecolor{black}

\multicolumn{1}{!{\huxvb{0, 0, 0}{0}}l!{\huxvb{0, 0, 0}{0}}}{\huxtpad{4pt}\raggedright BIC\huxbpad{4pt}} &
\multicolumn{1}{r!{\huxvb{0, 0, 0}{0}}}{\huxtpad{4pt}\raggedleft 130.5091~~~~\huxbpad{4pt}} &
\multicolumn{1}{r!{\huxvb{0, 0, 0}{0}}}{\huxtpad{4pt}\raggedleft 126.4769~~~~\huxbpad{4pt}} &
\multicolumn{1}{r!{\huxvb{0, 0, 0}{0}}}{\huxtpad{4pt}\raggedleft 127.0720~~~~\huxbpad{4pt}} &
\multicolumn{1}{r!{\huxvb{0, 0, 0}{0}}}{\huxtpad{4pt}\raggedleft 139.1500~~~~\huxbpad{4pt}} \tabularnewline[-0.5pt]

\hhline{>{\huxb{0, 0, 0}{0.8}}->{\huxb{0, 0, 0}{0.8}}->{\huxb{0, 0, 0}{0.8}}->{\huxb{0, 0, 0}{0.8}}->{\huxb{0, 0, 0}{0.8}}-}
\arrayrulecolor{black}

\end{tabularx}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Provided above is an example. Apologies if it isn't exactly `minimal' but I thought it may help in terms of specificity of the problem. I also included a frame around margins to help with visual inspection of centering.

Edit: Even if I were to reduce the name of my colleague's variable (which I admit is unwieldy) I still can not get the table to center correctly:

[image: Photo example here].

Ideally I'd like to center with as little adjustment as possible since RStudio automatically generates the LaTeX tables and I have many tables to include in my final document. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The problem is that the multicolumns use r,c or l column types, which by definition cannot wrap lines and their content is too wide. In particular the cells with `~~~~` are too wide. As as consequence the table gets extended to the right and no longer looks centred.

Comment: (all these \multicolumn{1}... don't make any sense, I would remove them all)

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of how the table should look like?

Comment: @samcarter Thank you for your response. I uploaded a screen shot of a modified interpretation of my challenge that shortens the columns to fit within margins. I hope this is somewhat helpful? ... I do agree that the table output is cumbersome. It is automatically generated using `jtools' in RStudio. Unfortunately my colleague has relied on it quite extensively on our project.

Answer (score 0):

This is a combination of several different problems:

- if you use a `tabularx` you should have at least one `X` column that can stretch to fit the table into the available space. In your original code the table had a total with of `.5\textwidth`, but you tried to fit in 5 columns of `.1\textwidth` each. This will never fit because it does not leave any room for the inter column separation.
- you use `p` columns with a fixed width, which is the right approach, but then you wrapped each and every cell in a `\multicolumn` with `c`, `l`, or `r` column types. This does not allow the text to wrap lines, hence your cells won't fit inside the fixed with columns. In fact these `\multicolumn`s cells which each span only one cell don't do anything good and only cause problems
- all these manual formatting interventions like `~~~~~~` will destroy any reasonable layout latex can come up with
- then you choose `.5\textwidth` as total with of the table - this is way too small. Even removing all the additional spaces inserted by `~~~~~` the text will not fit inside `.5\textwidth` and overflowing to the right hand side. This is why your table did not look centred. I suggest to make it span the whole `\textwidth` and even then the long words in the first column need to be broken across lines. (the boarders of the text area are shown in red in the screenshot below)

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}  
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=24cm,
%showframe
]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a4,frame,center]{crop}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

  \providecommand{\huxb}[2]{\arrayrulecolor[RGB]{#1}\global\arrayrulewidth=#2pt}
  \providecommand{\huxvb}[2]{\color[RGB]{#1}\vrule width #2pt}
  \providecommand{\huxtpad}[1]{\rule{0pt}{\baselineskip+#1}}
  \providecommand{\huxbpad}[1]{\rule[-#1]{0pt}{#1}}

\begin{center}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Xrrrr@{}}
\toprule
& Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3 & Model 4\\
\cmidrule{2-5}
Variables\-Intervention\-Incumbent &&& -0.0115 & 0.1432\\
\cmidrule{2-5}
BIC & 130.5091 & 126.4769 & 127.0720 & 139.1500\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(the boarders of the text area are shown in red)